# Variance of a non-linear function of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, standard-deviation, covariance

I know that the formula for Variance of a linear function of a random variable
is

$\textrm{var}(aX+b)=a^2\textrm{var}(X)$

But what about if the function is not-linear?

Is there any another formula to calculate it?

Comment: So is X the function or the random variable? It could be good to know what is the variable and what is the function.

Comment: X is a discrete random variable...

Comment: There is no simple answer. $\operatorname{var}(g(X)) = E[(g(X))^2] - (E[g(X)])^2$ but no further simplifications occur in the general case (including the one where $X$ is a discrete random variable.